# Python + Selenium web driver: Scraping table data returns incomplete results

Tags: python, css, selenium-webdriver

This is my first python project and would appreciate some help.

I'm trying to create a bot using selenium to automate appointment booking. The booking website has a calendar stored in css table like so:

[Calendar as it appears in the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixQ8p.png)

I'm trying to use driver.find_elements_by_xpath to extract all text from each cell in the table, but my code only returns some of the text elements.

Here's the code that I'm using:

```
    # click specified coordinates on calendar
    click_row = 2
    click_column = 3

    target_date = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/table/tbody/tr[' + str(click_row) + ']/td[' + str(click_column) +']')
    target_date.click()
```

That will successfully click on the date for July 6. But my ultimate goal is to tell Selenium to click "6" and it will find row 2 column 3 by itself, so I'll eventually compile a dataframe with the text inside the calendar cells, the corresponding row, and corresponding column. Here's the code I'm using to do that:

```
#get number of rows and columns in table
row_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/table/tbody/tr')
col_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td')
num_rows = len(row_elements)
num_cols = len(col_elements)

# list to hold dates
cells_list = []
for i in range(num_rows):#pulls all text in td tags and appends to cell_list
    for row in row_elements:
        cells = row.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")[i]
        cells_list.append(cells.text)
```

My code correctly finds the number of rows and columns in the calendar, but after I iterate through the results and append to the list 'cell_list', it only puts in 25 values. See output and picture for details.

```
    print('num_rows: ' +str(num_rows))
    print('num_cols: ' +str(num_cols))
    print(cells_list)

    Out:
    >>>num_rows: 5
    >>>num_cols: 7
    >>>['27', '今天', '11', '18', '25', '28', '5', '12', '19', '26', '29', '6', '13', '20', '27', '30', '7', '14', '21', '28', '1', '8', '15', '22', '29']
```

[What is and isn't extracted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zd8L3.png)

Why isn't my code pulling the last two columns of data?

Here's the website source code, and the [website for reference](https://yun.qingchengfit.cn/shop/16175/mobile/user/grouplesson/list/)(click on the upper-left corner to display the calendar):

```
   <div class="m-calendar">
   <div class="monthWrap">
      <div class="arrowWrap"><i class="arrow arrow-left"></i></div>
      <p>2021年07月</p>
      <div class="arrowWrap arrowWrap-right"><i class="arrow"></i></div>
   </div>
   <table class="calendarTable">
      <thead class="headerWrap">
         <tr>
            <th class="z-weekend">日</th>
            <th class="">一</th>
            <th class="">二</th>
            <th class="">三</th>
            <th class="">四</th>
            <th class="">五</th>
            <th class="z-weekend">六</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="calendarWrap">
         <tr>
            <td class="z-disabled">
               <span>27</span> <!---->
            </td>
            <td class="z-disabled">
               <span>28</span> <!---->
            </td>
            <td class="z-disabled">
               <span>29</span> <!---->
            </td>
            <td class="z-disabled">
               <span>30</span> <!---->
            </td>
            <td class="">
               <span>1</span> <!---->
            </td>
            <td class="">
               <span>2</span> <!---->
            </td>
            <td class="">
               <span>3</span> <!---->
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="z-today">
               <!----> <span>今天</span>
            </td>
            <td class="">
               <span>5</span> <!---->
            </td>
            <td class="">
               <span>6</span> <!---->
            </td>
            <td class="">
               <span>7</span> <!---->
            </td>
            <td class="z-active">
               <span>8</span> <!---->
            </td>
            <td class="">
               <span>9</span> <!---->
            </td>
            <td class="">
               <span>10</span> <!---->
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="">
               <span>11</span> <!---->
            </td>
            <td class="">
               <span>12</span> <!---->
            </td>
            <td class="">
               <span>13</span> <!---->
            </td>
            <td class="">
               <span>14</span> <!---->
            </td>
            <td class="">
               <span>15</span> <!---->
            </td>
            <td class="">
               <span>16</span> <!---->
            </td>
            <td class="">
               <span>17</span> <!---->
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="">
               <span>18</span> <!---->
            </td>
            <td class="">
               <span>19</span> <!---->
            </td>
            <td class="">
               <span>20</span> <!---->
            </td>
            <td class="">
               <span>21</span> <!---->
            </td>
            <td class="">
               <span>22</span> <!---->
            </td>
            <td class="">
               <span>23</span> <!---->
            </td>
            <td class="">
               <span>24</span> <!---->
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="">
               <span>25</span> <!---->
            </td>
            <td class="">
               <span>26</span> <!---->
            </td>
            <td class="">
               <span>27</span> <!---->
            </td>
            <td class="">
               <span>28</span> <!---->
            </td>
            <td class="">
               <span>29</span> <!---->
            </td>
            <td class="">
               <span>30</span> <!---->
            </td>
            <td class="">
               <span>31</span> <!---->
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't scrape it, just use the [api](https://yun.qingchengfit.cn/api/mobile/schedules/group/?shop_id=16175&date=2021-07-06)

Comment: Would love to, but reverse engineering private API's is a bit outside of my expertise, unless you know of an easier way to use the API?

Comment: `data = requests.get("https://yun.qingchengfit.cn/api/mobile/schedules/group/?shop_id=16175&date=2021-07-06").json()` will get you a dictionary with all the data for the 6th of July. You can simply change the date in the url to retieve data for other dates. This is just url hacking, not reverse engineering.